Skorokhod topology vs. weak topology
Let $\mathbb{D}([0,T],V)$ be the collection of the cadlag(right-continuous and has left limit) functions on $[0,T]$ taking values in a Hilbert space $V$. The space $\mathbb{D}$ is equipped with the Skorokhod topology.
Let $x_n\rightarrow x$ in $\mathbb{D}$ (in the Skorokhod topology). Do we have: For each $t\in[0,T]$, $x_n(t)$ converges weakly to $x(t)$ in $V$?(i.e. in the weak topology of $V$.)?
In fact, the situation I am dealing with is $V=L^2(U)$ where $U$ is a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

How do you define the Skorokhod topology with $V$ as value space? With the strong topology on $V$?

However you define it, the answer will be no, though. You will only have pointwise convergence in points $t \in [0,t]$ that are continuity points of $x$.

@user159517  It is defined by the collection of all processes that is cadlag in the sense of the strong topology in V.

@user159517 I see what you say, but I do not think that the fact you mentioned will disprove the weak convergence.

The answer is no. Let $T=1$. Let $u,v$ be orthonormal in $V$. Define $$ x_n(t) := \begin{cases} u, \quad t \in [0, 1/2 + 1/n) \\ v, \quad t \in [1/2 + 1/n, 1]   \end{cases}$$ and $$ x(t) := \begin{cases} u, \quad t \in [0, 1/2) \\ v, \quad t \in [1/2, 1]   \end{cases}$$
We convince ourselves that $x$ is the Skorokhod limit of $x_n$ : Define $$ \lambda_n(t) := \begin{cases} t(1+ 1/n), \quad  &t \in [0,1/2), \\
(1/2 + 1/2n) + (t-1/2)(1-1/n), \quad &t \in [1/2, 1] \end{cases}$$
Then, $\lambda_n$ uniformly converges to the identity, and since $x_n(\lambda_n(t)) = x(t)$ for $t \in [0,1]$, it holds that $x_n \to x$ with respect to the Skorokhod topology.
However, we have $(x_n (1/2), v) = (u,v) = 0$ while $(x(1/2),v) = (v,v) = 1$.

This is a simple but typical example, thank you!
